# How to project a 2D shape (Triangle) at a given angle

Tags: graphics, geometry, projection

I am trying to take an equilateral triangle and get it's projection at an angle of 60 degrees. I have the triangle already (`SSSTriangle[6, 6, 6]`) and I have tried to figure out how to use `Projection[]` but I have trouble figuring out how to employ this with vectors. I can also get the Radon transform at 60 degrees, but this is still not the actual 2D projection that I am trying to create. Neither of these options seems to be what I really want. How do I create this projection and visualize it? I know drawing it out, it should basically look like another triangle.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem was not well defined, as in 3D there are many ways to rotate object and many ways to project vectors and objects. As a demonstration I rotated you triangle around $x$, $y$ and $z$ axis by 60 degrees clockwise. If you run the code, you can rotate the 3D Graphics and take a look at it under different angles. Then I projected the triangles to the $xy$ plane. The code is written such that you can easily change the rotation axis and projection plane.

```
triangle = SSSTriangle[6, 6, 6]
basisX = {1, 0, 0};
basisY = {0, 1, 0};
basisZ = {0, 0, 1};
triangles3D = 
 Table[triangle /. {x_, y_} :> 
    RotationMatrix[60 Degree, v].{x, y, 0}, 
   {v, {basisX, basisY, basisZ}}]
Graphics3D[{FaceForm[None], EdgeForm[Black], triangles3D}, 
 Axes -> True, AxesLabel -> {x, y, z}, ViewPoint -> Top]
triangles2D = 
 triangles3D /. 
  p : {x_?NumberQ, y_, z_} :> {
    Projection[p, basisX].basisX, 
    Projection[p, basisY].basisY
   }
Graphics[{FaceForm[None], EdgeForm[Black], triangles2D}, Axes -> True,
  AxesLabel -> {x, y}]
```

> ```
> Triangle[{{0, 0}, {6, 0}, {3, 3 Sqrt[3]}}]
>
> {Triangle[{{0, 0, 0}, {6, 0, 0}, {3, (3 Sqrt[3])/2, 9/2}}], 
>  Triangle[{{0, 0, 0}, {3, 0, -3 Sqrt[3]}, {3/2, 
>     3 Sqrt[3], -((3 Sqrt[3])/2)}}], 
>  Triangle[{{0, 0, 0}, {3, 3 Sqrt[3], 0}, {-3, 3 Sqrt[3], 0}}]}
> ```
>
> [image]
>
> ```
> {Triangle[{{0, 0}, {6, 0}, {3, (3 Sqrt[3])/2}}], 
>  Triangle[{{0, 0}, {3, 0}, {3/2, 3 Sqrt[3]}}], 
>  Triangle[{{0, 0}, {3, 3 Sqrt[3]}, {3, 3 Sqrt[3]}}]}
> ```
>
> [image]